# Flash to IOS trying to load my flash program onto an ipad

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, openssl

I am trying to put the flash program I made onto an iPad and am seriously not managing.

I am following the steps from [this website](http://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/2011/11/30/flash-to-ios-a-step-by-step-tutorial-part-2/)

I have managed to get the certificate.  So right now in my openSSL bin folder I have the following two items.

- CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest
- ios_development.cer

Now in command prompt (this is my firs forray into command prompt so please be patient with me) when I type

```
openssl x509 -in developer_identity.cer -inform DER -out developer_identity.pem -outform PEM
```

I get the following error message

> Error opening Certificate developer_identity.cer
>       38280:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:.\crypto\bio
>       \bss_file.c:391:fopen('developer_identity.cer','rb')
>       38280:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:3
>       93:
>       unable to load certificate

Any help would be massively greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: In your command at the place where you write `developer_identity.cer` you need to write the path of the `.cer` file (like "C:\stuff\developer_identity.cer"), same with the `.pem file`

Comment: I forgot to mention that before I put it into the command promt I did go to the place where it is so it looked like this

openssl x509 -in developer_identity.cer -inform DER -out developer_identity.pem -outform PEM

Comment: Ok i wrote what you said and it seemed to get me to the next place

now it says i must input this line

  openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in developer_identity.pem -        out iphone_dev.p12

Which isnt working do I have to add the place again and where?

Thanks so much

Comment: do the same again for the parts that look like filenames, so `mkey.key`, `developer_identity.pem` and `iphone_dev.p12`.

Comment: Thanks I did that and I think it worked. It created all the files it was supposed but it never asked for a password like the tut says it should, I am stuck at another point now and I think when I am passed that point i will have to use the files I created

Comment: Okay I got out of that issue but the next part of tut definitely isnt working, it says I must paste following code in

 openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in developer_identity.pem -    out iphone_dev.p12

where do I put the path names and do i remove any of the words like inkey and in?